# Convert resultset in to Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

How can I convert the result of a LINQ query where I select some columns of a `DataTable` to a `DataTable` again?

```
DataTable dtN = new DataTable();

dtN.Columns.Add("Id");   
dtN.Columns.Add("Name");
dtN.AcceptChanges();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dtN.NewRow();
    dr["Id"] = i;  
    dr["Name"] = "A"+i.ToString();
    dtN.Rows.Add(dr);
    dtN.AcceptChanges();
}

var data = from r in dtN.AsEnumerable()
           select new { Name = r["Name"].ToString() };

//this line is giving error because CopyToDatatable is not available
DataTable dt = data.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable dtN = new DataTable();

dtN.Columns.Add("Id");
dtN.Columns.Add("Name");
dtN.AcceptChanges();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dtN.NewRow();
    dr["Id"] = i;
    dr["Name"] = "A" + i.ToString();
    dtN.Rows.Add(dr);
    dtN.AcceptChanges();
}

var data = from r in dtN.AsEnumerable()
            select new { Name = r["Name"].ToString() };

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
foreach(var s in data)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = s.Name;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
//DataTable dt = data.CopyToDataTable();
```

**EDIT :**
 `CopyToDataTable()` is only available on `IEnumerable<T>` where T is or derives from `DataRow`.

So in your first case `var data=from r in dtN.AsEnumerable() select r;`

`CopyToDataTable()` is available because your query returns an `IEnumerable<'DataRow>` .

But in the second case `var data = from r in dtN.AsEnumerable() select new { Name = r["Name"].ToString() };`

you are returning an **anonymous type**. 
Anonymous types don't carry the extension method for `CopyToDataTable()`.

If you wish to convert a non-datatable-derived T to a datatable, MSDN has a sample class that reflects out any type and performs the conversion .[Please Read this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your support.
var data = from r in dtN.AsEnumerable()
select r;

DataTable dt = data.CopyToDataTable();

Please see the above code block, I do not want to make a new table because it was just an example, in my scenario(real) there are many columns and i need 10 of them so i will have to make a new table and then will have to run a loop.

Comment: var data=from r in dtN.AsEnumerable() select r;

DataTable dt = data.CopyToDataTable();//this is available when we 
Select whole r(r is the full column in the datatable)

But when we use like this
var data = from r in dtN.AsEnumerable()
            select new { Name = r["Name"].ToString() };(not all the columns of the table then we do not get data.CopyToDataTable

data.CopyToDataTable()//here is the error

now you are saying that for this you will have to run the loop, but if i will be using the loop then what is the use of LINQ then

Comment: @user3129402 edited my answer. Hope that will help you

Comment: thanks for solving problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DataTable` with a lot of columns:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Foo",  typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Bar",  typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{"Foo",  "Max",   555});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{"Blub", "Marry", 123});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{"Bla",  "Mac",   999});
```

[image]

but you're only interested in a `DataTable` in one or some of the columns, but not all, you can simply use a `DataView`:

```
var nameOnlyTable = new DataView(dt).ToTable(false, new []{"Name"});
```

[image]

No need for LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for your support and answer, this can be a good alternate but if there are two collection and you are going to take a inner join and you select one column from first collection and another from the second collection using linq then this will not helpful but more or less it is good alternate. Thanks again